# How to use an object without knowing the objects' name

Tags: java, oop, object

I'm not too sure how to word this so it makes sense, but I'll try my best.

Say I have 2 classes. My main class, and a `Person` class.

My main class will create some Objects from the `Person` class like this

```
public class Example {

   static Person bob = new Person(23);//Age
   static Person fred = new Person(34);
   static Person John = new Person(28);
   //..and so on

   public static void main(String args[]){

       ..             

   }
}
```

and in my `Person` class..

```
public class Person{

    private int age;

    public Person(int age){
        this.age = age;
    }
    public int getAge(){
        return this.age;
    }
}
```

Now, if I wanted the age of fred, I'd just call `Fred.getAge();`.
But, in my program, I don't know what person I'm getting the age of. It randomly selects one, and I need to get the name without directly calling the object. For example, I would have something like this in my Person class:

```
public static Object getPerson(){

    //Some code to get a random integer value and store it it Var
    switch(Var){
    case 1:
        return bob;
    case 2:
        return fred;
    case 3:
        return john;
    }
}
```

What I would expect this to do is return an Object that I could then use like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]){

        System.out.println(Person.getPerson().getAge());

}
```

What I thought that would have done was first call `getPerson()` which randomly returns either `bob`, `fred`, or `john`, and then it would call `getAge()`. So if `getPerson()` returned `fred` then it would be the same as doing `fred.getAge();`

Now, this doesnt work, and this was the only way I thought of that made sense to me.

How do I do this so it actually does what I want?

*I'm very new to Java, and OOP, and this is my first time really working with different Objects. So I'm sorry if I'm using the wrong terms and explaining things weirdly.*

Comment: "Now, this doesnt work, and this was the only way I thought of that made sense to me." - what exactly means "doesn't work" here? Has any exception occurred?

Comment: how are you randomly retrieving a person?

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to accomplish.  Normally, you would have a request that states, "get fred's age", thus you would iterate through an array of "Person" and find "Fred" and print age (thus, needing a "getName() on object.  Or, you can simply create an array of "Person"'s and iterate through them and print their ages.

Comment: Can not believe number of silly answers to a simple questions. Just type cast it `System.out.println(((Person)Person.getPerson()).getAge());`

Comment: Variable names should start in lowercase. Correct `John` and `Var`.

Comment: If my comment helps you please let me know I will post it as an answer. Seems a lot of confusion about the problem. I believe you want to know how to call a method if object is very generic . In that case you will have to TypeCast it to convert it to a type where this method exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
public static Object getPerson(){
```

to

```
public static Person getPerson(){
```

You can't call getAge on an Object, because the Object type does not have getAge() defined.

Comment: I reaaly don't get why somebody downvoted this answer... It's solves the problem...

Answer (score 3):

Why not put the name as a property of the Person class?

```
class Person {
    // ... your existing code for age...
    private String name;

    String getName() { return name; }

    // add name to constructor...
    public Person(String name, int age) {
        // set them up here...
    }
}
```

The way I see it, is that `name` is for you as a human, but variables `john` are irrelivant to the program and computer.... you can even use `p1 = Person("Joe", 42);`

To get a person by age, you can use a `Map` with age as key, and person as value.

Answer (score 1):

It could be the case that this is a misunderstanding, but how I'm interpreting the issue is as follows:

- You need a (better) place to store all of your `Person` objects instead of having them as `static` variables.
- You need a way to randomly select from wherever you're storing those objects.

Let's address the main issue first.  You're creating these as static variables when they *probably* shouldn't be; they should just be created as entries into an array.

The way to do this is through this declaration:

```
Person[] people = new Person[] {new Person(23), new Person(34), new Person(28)};
```

The main issue *now* is that you have no way to refer to which person's age belongs to whom since you haven't attached a `name` field to any of these instances.  You *could* do that easily:

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private String age;  

    public Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name; 
        this.age = age;
    }

    // getters for name and age
}
```

...then you can instantiate your `Person` with two values.

```
new Person("Bob", 23);
```

Now that we've addressed one concern (which was where to store the people in the first place), now we need a way to randomly access them.

For that, we can use [`Random#nextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)).

```
Random rand = new Random();
System.out.println("Person's age - " + people[rand.nextInt(people.length)]);
```

This will randomly pull a `Person` out of the array and print their age.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a random person within the person class you could store a reference to each person created, and then select randomly from that list

```
public class Person {
    // A List of every Person Created.
    private static final List<Person> allPeople = new ArrayList<People>();

    // A source of random numbers
    private static final Random rand = new Random();
    ...
    public Person(int age) {
       ...
       // Every time we create a new Person, store a reference to that person.
       addPerson(this);
    }

    // synchronized as ArrayLists are not thread safe.  
    private static synchronized addPerson(Person person) {
       allPeople.add(person);
    }

    ...
    public static Person getRandomPerson() {
        // Get a random number between zero and the size of the list.
        int random = rand.nextInt(allPeople.size() -1);

        return allPeople.get(random);

    }
```

Now this code is not what I would do in a production environment but it the question sounds like an exercise. A better way would be to store the people created in a List in your Example class. But trying to answer the question as you asked it.